# #include, error LNK2005

Tags: c++, include, lnk2005

Alirhgt, i tried to sort this one out myslef but can't. So, i have a task to build a paint program in the console, i have a set of functions dealing with the console. My task being only to connect them logically to do something useful. The problem is that everytime i #include the two files given : the .h and the .cpp file, i get the LNK2005 error that they are already defined. If i only include the header file, the functions don't do anything( i tried using one function but the console just stood there doing nothing). Can anybody tell me what i'm doing wrong? I haven't worked with C++ in a bit, so i might be doing some stupid mistake.

Comment: We don't have enough information.  For starters, you should `#include` the .h file, *not* the .cpp file.  Show us some source code and *exact* error messages, and we might be able to help.  And if this is homework, please add a [tag:homework] tag.

Comment: You simply missing to link some library (because its linker error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you should never include cpp files.

Second, you might need include guards.
Format headers like this:

```
#ifndef FILE_H
#define FILE_H

struct foo {
    int member;
};

#endif
```

You can read about why from here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Comment: Yes, but neither of those will address the symptom the OP is reporting: "the console just stood there doing nothing".

Comment: Hmm.  I'm curious how this solved the "console just stood there doing nothing" problem.